# Are ids automitaclly encrypted in Graphql queries?

Tags: graphql, relay

In my database (postgres) I store a table of events and each event has an "id" column which is a UUID type. But when I send a GraphQL query the id I receive back is not a string UUID but looks like some encrypted version.

I'm using Relay and Graphene on the server side if that information helps.

```
query {
  allEvents {
    edges {
      node {
        id
      }
    }
  }
}


{
  "data": {
    "allEvents": {
      "edges": [
        {
          "node": {
            "id": "RXZlbnQ6NzRkZTIxZmUtZWQyNy00OTg1LTk2NjEtNmU4ZDUzMGEwMjQ3"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A frequent implementation choice is to base64-encode IDs and cursor values (the query you show follows [Relay's pagination conventions](https://relay.dev/docs/guides/graphql-server-specification/#connections)). If you base64-decode the string you put in the question, you'll find a UUID again.

At a GraphQL level, `ID` is nothing more or less than an opaque ID.  [The spec](https://graphql.github.io/graphql-spec/June2018/#sec-ID) itself doesn't say much about it, other than that it serializes as a string but could accept a number as input instead.  Most more application-oriented server libraries I've worked with don't put much in the way of special semantics around `ID` either, like other scalar types it gets passed in and out as-is.

The last paragraph of the documentation on [Relay's object identification scheme](https://relay.dev/docs/guides/graphql-server-specification/#object-identification) (the `node` top-level query) also has a strong opinion that applications shouldn't be synthesizing `ID` values, and so the base64 encoding at least hints to consumers that the value isn't supposed to be understood. The base64 encoding here isn't anything generic or hard-coded in GraphQL, and an application or library could choose a different `ID` scheme if it wanted.